# Is there an improvement for this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I have written down very simple Python codes to add various dollar bills or coins and it turns out to be very long. Please advise me if there is an improvement for it so that I can make it more efficient.

```py
#User input
a = int(input('Enter the number of hundreds: '))
b = int(input('Enter the number of fifties: '))
c = int(input('Enter the number of twenties: '))
d = int(input('Enter the number of tens: '))
e = int(input('Enter the number of fives: '))
f = int(input('Enter the number of one: '))
g = int(input('Enter the number of quarters: '))
h = int(input('Enter the number of dimes: '))
i = int(input('Enter the number of nickels: '))
j = int(input('Enter the number of pennies: '))

def hun(k):
    return 100 * k
def fif(l):
    return 50 * l
def twe(m):
    return 20 * m
def ten(n):
    return 10 * n
def fiv(o):
    return 5 * o
def one(p):
    return 1 * p
def qua(q):
    return .25 * q
def dim(r):
    return .10 * r
def nic(s):
    return .05 * s
def pen(t):
    return .01 * t

# Final computation

total = hun(a) + fif(b) + twe(c) + ten(d) + fiv(e) + one(f) + qua(g) + dim(h) + nic(i) + pen(j)
print('The total amount is $', total)
```

Comment: Questions asking for improvements to style of working code should be posted to [codereview.se]. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn’t trying to resolve a _specific_ programming problem. As @Barmar notes, it would be more appropriate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your code with a dictionary and the `sum()` method:

```
c = {'hundreds':100,
     'fifties':50,
     'twenties':20,
     'tens':10,
     'fives':5,
     'one':1,
     'quarters':.25,
     'dimes':.1,
     'nickels':.05,
     'pennies':.01}

total = sum(int(input(f"Enter the number of {k}: "))*c[k] for k in c)

print(f"The total amount is ${total}.")
```